# Can I have a screenshot of "Lagrangian of $\phi^4$ theory"?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

This [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89423/lagrangian-of-phi-4-theory) has been deleted. To me, the question was quite interesting. Can I have a screenshot of the entire question?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope it's appropriate to post this. I can't think why it wouldn't be, so...

[image]

Comment: For something deleted by Community, it's generally fine. I would exercise caution (whatever that means) in cases where the post was deleted for being spam or offensive though. If it was deleted by a moderator (or the post owner), in most cases it will still be fine but you should ask the person who deleted it first. Or in case of deletion by moderator, if that moderator is not reachable for some reason, ask one of the other mods and we'll work it out.